# Is dynamically loading CSS and Javascript Hackish or Good Practice?

Tags: css, dynamic

I don't want to start a flame war, but I'm curious what people think.

The benefits I can think of for dynamically loading:

- Load files as you need them. Faster
  load times
- You can create widgets that hook into your page with just linking to
  the widget and the widget loads all
  its files

Some (possible) negatives:

- Loading stuff in the head after it
  loads (am I just scared of doing
  that? :-P)
- Ensuring that the code is evaluated.
- Javascript being turned off.

Let me know what you think!

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Does it really take up *that* much bandwidth?  I consider the smallest part of any web application I've developed to be JavaScript / CSS.  Plus, the browser caches it anyway, it's only the first hit that really counts.  There's no point adding complexity to defeat such a small issue.

**EDIT**

Building on from my comment, there's some really good articles around on how you should develop using JavaScript.  The general idea is to develop your application in a layered manner.  Javascript just sits on the top, but it's not fundamental to the functioning of your website.  With Javascript disabled everything should work fine.  Always develop as if the user doesn't have Javascript enabled (some users disable it purely for performance reasons).  It's good practice.

Comment: My websites are like 98% javascript and 2% CSS, HTML haha. Lots of AJAX and Page manipulations.

Comment: I should say thats how my front-end looks.

Comment: To be honest, you should be careful with Javascript.  *Always* develop as if the user doesn't have Javascript enabled.  Then once it works fine, add Javascript.  This is called progressive enhancement, with elegant degradation.  With Javascript enabled, brilliant, but with it disabled, it should still work fine.

Comment: True, but that depends entirely on the requirements of the site. Most sites can be made to work without JavaScript, but some of them are simply too directed at "modern internet features" to be worth making text-browser compatible. Basically: information sites should work without JavaScript, interactive sites doesn't necessarily have to. Try to do something interactive (search, view movie, ...) on http://www.youtube.com/ with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Yah. Both of you make good points. The types of websites I make fall into the category Blixt mentioned, with lots of drag and drop, live search and slideshows.

Answer (score 1):

I generally compress all my CSS into one file and all my JavaScript required to use the page into another (using YUICompressor.) Then I load those two files statically in the HTML document. It'll show the content as early as possible to your users (even if they might not get a nice loading indicator while waiting), and it'll use less server resources.

If I have JavaScript/other content that will be required after user interaction, I load that dynamically. I haven't really worked with many projects that benefited from dynamic loading, but here's one I did for my JavaScript libraries: ["Blixt's JavaScript Realm"](http://blixt.org/js) (but the reason it has so much dynamic loading is because the whole purpose of that project was to make it as JavaScript-ish as possible...)

Answer (score 1):

on a very large popular site you want to minimise the total number of http requests, even small ones. Amazon and Ebay go great lengths to do this and even use techniques called css image sprites to load all thier front page images as one giant gif or jpeg and then use CSS to slice them up, all to save the overhead of each HTTP GET request, each request avoided can save as a few hundred bytes.

Comment: A few hundred bytes isn't the main reason to reduce the number of requests if you ask me; there's a CPU/memory overhead incurred by each individual request which is more likely to take down a server than some additional bandwidth use.

Comment: So are you advocating to just load it all as one and compress it up? Instead of loading packages as needed?